# How to hyperlink hover effect image without messing up the layout for website template

Tags: html, css

I'm using this html5 website template.

Is there a simple way to add hyperlink to another website when I hover to the image and click?

I believe something to do with the bootstrap grid (class = "col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item").

```
<!-- Portfolio 1 -->
                <section id="two">
                    <h1><strong>My Portfolio</strong></h1>
                    <div class="row">
                        <article class = "col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
                            <a href="images/fulls/01.jpg" class ="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h3>SQL: COVID-19 Data Exploration</h3>
                            <p>This is a project about COVID-19 cases.</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
                            <a href="images/fulls/02.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs/02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h3>Tableau: COVID-19 Dashboard</h3>
                            <p>This is a project about COVID-19 cases dashboard.</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
                            <a href="images/fulls/03.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs/03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h3>Portfolio Project 3</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nisl sed nullam feugiat.</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
                            <a href="images/fulls/04.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs/04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h3>Portfolio Project 4</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nisl sed nullam feugiat.</p>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQNHf.png)

Comment: What you are looking for is Tool TIps, you can read about them here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: Are you trying to go to another website when that image is hovered?

Comment: @Millhorn Yes, I want to go to another website when I hover to the image and click it.

Comment: Would all the images go to the same site? or would they be different?

Comment: I had an answer there, but removed it. You said you want to **"go to another website when I hover to the image and click it."**... Do you want to go to the other site when you hover the image or click the image?

Comment: Hi @Millhorn, thank you for helping me. This is really new for me. I want to go to the other website when I click the image. I don't need the slideshow image. Just one image to display and when I click, it will direct to the other website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment above, you don't need anything fancy. Your images were already wrapped in anchor tags. You just need to add the URL to the `href` attribute and you're good to go. I've redone my answer below.

Hope this helps.

```html
<!-- Portfolio 1 -->
<section id="two">
  <h1><strong>My Portfolio</strong></h1>
  <div class="row">
    <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
      <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="image fit thumb">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt=""/>
      </a>      
      <h3>SQL: COVID-19 Data Exploration</h3>
      <p>This is a project about COVID-19 cases.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="image fit thumb">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt=""/>
      </a>
      <h3>Tableau: COVID-19 Dashboard</h3>
      <p>This is a project about COVID-19 cases dashboard.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
      <a href="https://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank" class="image fit thumb">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt=""/>
      </a>
      <h3>Portfolio Project 3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nisl sed nullam feugiat.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
      <a href="https://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" class="image fit thumb">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt=""/>
      </a>
      <h3>Portfolio Project 4</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nisl sed nullam feugiat.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This adds the event on hover, not when clicking. I wouldn't recommend that setup as a user may not want to go to another website just with hovering over something

Answer (score 2):

To show a tooltip with a link when the image is hovered, create an `<a>` tag immediately after the image and set it to `display: none` unless it or the image are hovered, like so:

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
}

img:not(:hover)+a:not(:hover) {
  display: none;
}

img+a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Jonquil_flowers06.jpg/473px-Jonquil_flowers06.jpg" />
  <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Flowers">Here's where this picture came from</a>
</div>
```